# Invoking Java Code with Acceleo

Tags: eclipse, templates, model, acceleo

I try to invoke some java code in a template with Acceleo. 
The code given there : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/FAQ#How_to_use_a_Java_service_in_Acceleo works fine but my code doesn't and I don't find any error.

Here my java function :

```
public String test(softo.Activite activity) {
     return activity.getModXName();
}
```

and the template code :

```
[query public getTest(a : Activite) : String = invoke('org.eclipse.acceleo.softogen.files.Utility','test(softo.Activite activity)', Sequence{a}) /]
[template public createOperationUrl(activity : AccessibleActivite) ]
Result : [getTest(activity)/]
[/template]
```

I also tried to replace the return function by return 'foobar' but it doesn't work either. 
I don't have any message when I generate : the file just contains 'Result :'.
I also have checked the paths and the filenames I use.

Any idea to solve the problem ?

Edit : 
Okay ! I finally found the answer... it's really stupid : in the query code you don't have to put the argument name, only their type, so :

```
[query public getTest(a : Activite) : String = invoke('org.eclipse.acceleo.softogen.files.Utility','test(softo.Activite activity)', Sequence{a}) /]
```

became :

```
[query public getTest(a : Activite) : String = invoke('org.eclipse.acceleo.softogen.files.Utility','test(softo.Activite)', Sequence{a}) /]
```

and it works... Good to know =)

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two queries... they look the same. I have the same problem as you, how did you solve it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you exported the package containing the Java service in your manifest? If not, open the file MANIFEST.MF, then go to the runtime tab and there, export the package containing the Java class. You can also try to throw a new `RuntimeException()` before the "return" in your Java method if you want to be sure that the service is called.

Comment: The package is well exported. But thanks for the answer I might have forget that. I tried to launch a RuntimeException and actually the function isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

Not really related, but you should take the habit of using this syntax:

```
activity.getTest()
```

instead of

```
getTest(activity)
```